# Adding Sounds to Xcode 4.3

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, avaudioplayer

I've looked at many tutorials but all of them are too confusing or outdated. How can I add sounds to Xcode 4.3? If there is a good tutorial out there you can just show me it. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the SIMPLEST way to play a sound clip in an iPhone app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/896331/whats-the-simplest-way-to-play-a-sound-clip-in-an-iphone-app)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a **very** vague question. I'm also fairly sure (from looking at the iPhone tag) that you don't want to add sounds to Xcode, you want to play sounds in an iPhone app.

If you do truly want to add a sound to your Xcode project, then you drag the audio file into your project or import it through the menus.

If you want to play audio, then you should use [AVAudioPlayer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html). This tutorial [here](http://mobileorchard.com/easy-audio-playback-with-avaudioplayer/) is about as simply and well as it can be explained, so there is no point in me rephrasing it. Just take a look and you should be good.

The tutorial even offers example code.

Comment: Thanks! I will give the tutorial a shot. I understand I asked the question in a bad way, I'll try to do better next time.